# Ninject with Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, ninject

I would like use ninject dependency injector in my WorkerRole app.
But I catch some problems. After run my worker role he instantly crashed, and I don't know why it happens.

**My WorkerRole.cs code:**

```
public class WorkerRole : NinjectRoleEntryPoint
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private readonly ManualResetEvent _runCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        private IKernel _kernel;
        public ITestA TestA { get; }
        protected WorkerRole(ITestA testA)
        {
            TestA = testA;
        }

        public override void Run()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerRole1 is running");

            try
            {
                RunAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
            }
            finally
            {
                _runCompleteEvent.Set();
            }
        }

        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel();
            _kernel.Bind<ITestA>().To<TestA>();

            return _kernel;
        }

        private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // TODO: Replace the following with your own logic.
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                TestA.Hello();

                Trace.TraceInformation("Working");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

and I created one simple interface and class for it, like this:

```
public interface ITestA
    {
        void Hello();
    }

    public class TestA: ITestA
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ninject with Worker Role!");
        }
    }
```

This all, I don't know why my apps crashed, help me please with this issues.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure it allows you to inject right into the WorkerRole constructor. Constructor is called far before you create a kernel, so you won't likely be able to do it.

Comment: @raderick I think yes, but it is not fix my problems with crashing apps after run

Comment: Does it even step to one of your methods? I'm afraid you have to set up logging and try to catch your exception, code looks more or less clean to me except for the constructor.

Comment: @raderick hmmm, maybe you know where I need get some manual about Ninject and WorkerRoles.

Comment: You can try this one - one of first lines in google: http://www.thisdevmind.com/2015/01/20/how-im-using-dependency-injection-with-ioc-container-in-azure-workerroles/ . I also recommend to do your code step by step to determine the issue: 1. create empty web role, run 2. inherit from NinjectRoleEntryPoint, run 3. override method-by-method and at some point you will find the issue.

Comment: @raderick ahaha, yes I use it, it is not working, all similarly ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98988/discussion-between-taras-kovalenko-and-raderick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue most likely happens because you keep NinjectRoleEntryPoint and WorkerRole in the same Worker Role project. You should only keep **one** `RoleEntryPoint` implementation in your Worker Role project, and your `NinjectRoleEntryPoint` should be moved to a separate class library project.

In short - you cannot have multiple classes that inherit RoleEntryPoint in one Worker Role, by design.